# Laravel Sanctum : blocked by CORS policy with Nuxt Auth module

Tags: cors, nuxt.js, laravel-7, laravel-valet, laravel-sanctum

I have a **Laravel** website served by [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/master/valet) on `backend.test` and a **Nuxt** SPA on `nuxt.backend.test:3005`. When I try to authenticate to [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/master/sanctum#spa-authentication) with [Nuxt Auth](https://dev.auth.nuxtjs.org/providers/laravel-sanctum.html) module, I get the CORS error below:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://backend.test/login' from origin
>   'http://nuxt.backend.test:3005' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

How can I fix it ?

**Laravel configuration**

`config/cors.php`:

```
<?php

return [
    'paths' => ['*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
];
```

`routes/api.php`:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

`app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        ...
        'api' => [
            EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

`.env`:

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="backend.test"
SESSION_DOMAIN=".backend.test"
```

**Nuxt configuration**
`nuxt.config.js`:

```
export default {
  server: {
    port: '3005',
    host: 'nuxt.backend.test'
  },
  ...
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
  ],
  axios: {
    proxy: true
  },
  proxy: {
    '/nuxt': {
      target: 'nuxt.backend.test',
      pathRewrite: { '^/nuxt': '/' }
    }
  },
  auth: {
    redirect: {
      callback: '/auth/callback'
    },
    strategies: {
      laravelSanctum: {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: 'http://backend.test'
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

`pages/index.php`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <pre>{{ $auth.user }}</pre>
    </div>
    <button @click="signIn()">Sign in</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    signIn() {
      this.$auth.loginWith('laravelSanctum', {
        data: {
          email: 'me@home.com',
          password: '1qaz@WSX'
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Laravel** backend and **Nuxt** frontend have to be under the same domain, so I finally fixed it in 3 steps:

#### 1. Add this to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   nuxt.backend.test
```

#### 2. Using the beta version of `@nuxt/auth`:

```
npm remove @nuxtjs/auth
npm install @nuxtjs/auth-next @nuxtjs/axios
```

In `nuxt.config.js`, use:

```
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
  ],
```

#### 3. Using the configuration below:

```
{
  axios: {
    proxy: true
  },
  proxy: {
    '/laravel': {
      target: 'http://backend.test',
      pathRewrite: { '^/laravel': '/' }
    }
  },
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      laravelSanctum: {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: '/laravel'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, replacing `backend.test` and `nuxt.backend.test` by `localhost` and removing **Nuxt** server `host` from `nuxt.config.js` and then use `php artisan serve` instead of **Valet** for **Laravel** is fine too.

Comment: I'm trying to make Nuxt work with Laravel's Sanctum but i have encountered few issues. I want know if you have a full working example or a code base I can use?

Comment: @xperator Unfortunately not. I'm now using Laravel Passport which better fits my needs.

Comment: Ah I see.. For me I spent like 3 days to get the basic login page to work. Right now the problem is when I enable `auth` middleware, the app keeps redirecting to the `/login` page even though the `this.$auth.loggedIn` is `true` and the `api/user/` from laravel side returns the right user information

Comment: I'm wondering if Laravel Passport is more or less of the same experience..? I just want a very simple classic user/pass login authentication, no fancy tokens or social network auth is needed